# Where is MergeOption in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm used to Entity Framework 4, where, when calling certain views I had to be sure to set `MergeOption` to `NoTracking` like so

```
SHEntity.qry_UserPermissions.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;
```

But in updating to EF 6.1 I don't even see `MergeOption` as part of `qry_UserPermissions` anymore. I have to set this or EF will sometimes combine records when I don't want it to. I've googled around and haven't had any luck, even though it seems like a simple issue to me.

How do I turn off tracking in EF 6.1?

Comment: Have you tried the [AsNoTracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx)-Extension?

Comment: @user3411327 I have not, though it seems surprising that I'd have to use an extension method to do this now

Comment: I assumed you switched from ObjectContext and ObjectQueries to DbContext and DbSets. DbSet does not provide the MergeOption-Property like ObjectQuery does.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

using AsNotrack() method entity, you may stop tracking of entity in EF 
this can be written we you querying on context.

Example.

```
using (SHEntity context = new SHEntity())
{
   var up = context.qry_UserPermissions.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```